# How do I interpret the Excluded Changes tree in the Pending Changes window?

Tags: version-control, tfs, azure-devops

What is the status of the files and directories in the screenshot?

[image]

It looks like it's telling me that I've changed them all but I haven't - I checked them out and haven't touched them at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you checkout a file in TFS it gets included in the pending changes. That's how it works. As you are using TFS 2012, you probably want a [Local Workspace](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/11/02/local-workspaces-in-tfs-2012.aspx) to get a more subversion style Pending Changes, where it only shows files that have actual changes.

Comment: Thanks. Is there some logic behind that? Right now I wish I was using Hg or Git and it might like TFS if I understood it...

Comment: I don't think so, it's the old VSS way of working with Check-out check-in. As I said, Local Workspaces are more Subversion Style so should be easier to work with.

Comment: No that says "Server". Are you using TFS 2012 or 2010? Local Workspaces should be available in 2012.

Comment: But it's named after my machine and it stays visible when I uncheck "Show remote workspaces" on the Manage Workspaces screen. Also, the files themselves are on my machine. Seems pretty local to me.

Comment: A Remote Workspace is a Server Workspace owned by you on another machine. A local workspace is one the Server knows nothing about. The "Location:" is the important bit here.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Another one of Microsoft's tools that they make confusing on purpose so they can sell books and training.

Comment: Unfortunately we are on TFS 2010. Mercurial it is then.

Comment: It was you who tagged the question as TFS 2012 ;). I would have been able to explain it better had I known that. No worries :)

Comment: No problem. I'm new to TFS and used the TFS version number from Help > About in VS. I didn't realise the server might be a different version.

Comment: @cja the logic behind it is that it prevents scanning your working folders for changes, which may be expensive if you have a large repository and/or large files in that repository and server workspaces are optimized for those cases.  If your model is to explicitly check files out, the client need not compute a hash of files needlessly.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I should have known that :o.

Comment: @DaveShaw It's one of those details that doesn't make any sense and you curse until you really need it.  Of course, that doesn't happen all that often, which is why local workspaces became the default in 2012.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, but presumably they could have achieved the same by providing a refresh button and never refreshing automatically. TortoiseHg does this.

Comment: @cja No, that's just moving the scanning, not eliminating it.  On a server workspace we *never* want to scan the disk for changes.  Changing it to being driven manually still crawls my 20 GB source code enlistment, which I *never* want to happen.

Comment: So it's better for the user to have to identify the changes files themselves? Instead the user knows which project they want to check in and they can refresh that project, not the whole 20GB.

Comment: Only files that the user checks out are need to be checked and tracked, the system doesn't have to scan to find them. Remember, this is all from the VSS days, before computers and networks are what they are today. Enterprises still had large code bases back then though - that's what it was designed for :).